# My PHP MySQL while loop does not return results

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

```
<?php
$sqls = mysql_query("SELECT weight FROM $usertablestats")
or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $query);
$ct = mysql_query ("COUNT * '$sqls'");

if ($ct > 0) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqls));{
      $weight = $row["weight"];
      echo "C" . $weight;
    }}
else {
  echo "No stats found";
}
?>
```

This outputs "No stats found" even though I have data in the table.

```
<?php
$sqls = mysql_query("SELECT weight FROM $usertablestats")
or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $query);
$ct = mysql_num_rows($sqls);

if ($ct > 0) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqls));{
      $weight = $row["weight"];
      echo "C" . $weight;
    }}
else {
  echo "No stats found";
}
?>
```

This returns nothing. No echo at all.

I have checked to see if it is accessing by just using:

```
<?php
   $sqls = mysql_query("SELECT weight FROM $usertablestats")
   or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $query);

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($sqls);

   echo $row;
?>
```

And it does return the first entry.

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolon in while :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqls));{
//should be
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqls)){
```

Is that causing problem

Comment: //Thank you!  I am new at this, and I knew it had to be something really stupid on my part.  It worked great.  I don't suppose there is a way to subtract the last row from the first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$sqls = mysql_query("SELECT weight FROM $usertablestats")
or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $query);

int $ct = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqls)){
    $weight = $row["weight"];
    echo "C" . $weight;
    $ct++;
}

if ($ct == 0) {
    echo "No stats found";
}

?>
```

If it doesn't work then make sure that `$usertablestats` has the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqls,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $weight = $row["weight"];
    echo "C" . $weight;
    $ct++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sqls = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $usertablestats")
or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $query);

if (mysql_num_rows($sqls)!=0) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqls)){
   $weight = $row["weight"];
   echo "C" . $weight;
}}
else {
   echo "No stats found";
}
?>
```